# Google script error in setFormula when using SUMIF function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script that will fill in a Google spreadsheet with data including formulas. I can't seem to get it to accept the formula if it uses SUMIF.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("D2");
cell.setForumla('=SUMIF(B25:B, "0*", K25:K)');
```

The last line errors out with: `TypeError: Cannot find function setForumla in object Range.`

I'm just trying to sum column K if the corresponding value in column B begins with 0.

I found a thread that suggested using  `\"` instead of `"` around the comparison value but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's just a simple spelling mistake.

setForumla instead of setFormula

Comment: I must have had a Homer Simpson moment! Yikes, thanks for catching that.